# 3D radar chart in JavaScript

Tags: graph, 3d, javascript

Is there a JavaScript library that allows you to visualize Radar Chart (aka Spider Chart) in 3D form along with the rotation.

What I mean by that is to visualize [this](http://www.larsko.org/v/euc/) kind of chart in 3D by adding time as a coordinate. The end result will be a 3D sphere that is not symmetrically shaped. For example:

[image]

I tried to search all different 3D JavaScript libraries but was not able to find anything that will let me do it easily without creating it from scratch.

Comment: Can you not just create some timer that at regular intervals changes dataset and redraws the chart?

Answer (score 1):

What about [`D3`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/)? There aren't many chart types that *can't* be visualized with it.

More information at [GitHub](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D3.js).